# Responsive text in a JavaFX-Label

Tags: java, javafx

I created a label with a number shown in it and I now want to make this number responsive to the GUI. How can I do that? Here is my number with its current font-size.

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setText("12");
label.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", 35));
```

If I start the application in a different window-size the size of the number should match the window. At the moment the size of the number stays 35 all the time and is therfore too big for a smaller window. 
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Should the text fit exactly from one side of the window to the other, with no margin on either side?

Comment: Register a listener with the bounds of the window (or maybe some ancestor of the label in the scene graph) and update the font size accordingly when it changes. Without more details about exactly what your layout is, it's impossible to give a more detailed answer.